# Network, wifi, advance

Tags: network, macos

I've have found these on System Preferences: Wifi, Advance then Proxies.
Why do I need to use passiveftp mode (pasv) and Bypass proxy settings for those Hosts & Domains.: *.local, 169.254 16

I don't have any FTP or either a Domain Account.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear all the proxy settings unless you know you need to route some or all internet traffic through one single point of failure and slowdown.